# Simplest code for 64-bit block RSA-like encryption/decryption and key generation

Tags: encryption

Looking for the simplest code in C. Need a set of functions that will first generate a public/private 64-bit key pair, and then the function to code/decode a given 64-bit block, no built-in checksum or anything more advanced is needed.

Comment: For something like RSA you need larger block than 64 bits. The parameter size currently is around 2048 bits. Furthermore, _crypto.stackexchange.com_ is for questions on cryptography, not for requests to provide implementation. Please, reconsider what you need (for instance study RSA bit more so you know what you need) and then ask again on a more appropriate forum, possibly, _stackoverflow.com_.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, 64-bit RSA is terminally unsafe: [hand the modulus to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16807708473783470801) and its factorization is returned among other trivia. Some [mention of use of 64-bit RSA in commercial products](http://dogber1.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/shmuck-of-month-sony.html) can still be found, but do not count on Crypto.SE for any recommendation about that.

More generally, we know no method comparable in goal to RSA encryption that is even mildly secure when either the key or the ciphertext is 64-bit. In fact there are good arguments this can't exist.

If what you want is a 64-bit [**block cipher**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) with fair cryptographic security, there are many good choices, including [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) with a random secret key which nicely matches the *simplest code in C* requirement. You however loose the possibility to encipher with a *public* key.

If you like TEA except that you also want the key to be 64-bit, there are solutions better than shortening the key, by using some slow key derivation function; or at least, very much upping the number of rounds. Just better state what the 64-bit size constraint is exactly, and you'll likely get a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of block ciphers, but I really need a public key encryption. I'd like to cipher a certain data so that nobody beside me could create such ciphered data. In essense, what is called public key I'd like to keep for myself, the private (deciphering) key will be public. Well, maybe 96-bit RSA will be OK? 128-bit is longer than I need, but if it's a minimum I may reconsider my requirement. Maybe I'm wrong with such approach (ciphering key is private, deciphering key is public) and this just can't be done.

Comment: You mention _I'd like to cipher a certain data so that nobody beside me could create such ciphered data_. RSA, when used to _encipher_, has the reverse property: anyone can encipher, only you can decipher. RSA can also be used to _sign_, so that only you can sign a message, anyone can verify the signature. In both cases, the cryptogram is at least (about) 1024-bit for something safe against hackers (but possibly not the NSA). There are signature systems with much shorter signature, e.g. [BLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh%E2%80%93Lynn%E2%80%93Shacham), but that won't be few lines of C.

Comment: Thanks again. Well, I'm probably wrong with my request. What I needed is a way to cipher data, not just sign it. So upon deciphering you get the privately ciphered data, not just an indication of authenticity.